# How do I find the number of grams of the product when given reactants?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, mole

I have the following chemical equation

$$\ce{H + O2 -> H2O}$$

which balances out to

$$\ce{4H + O2 -> 2H2O}$$

How would I find out how many grams of $\ce{H2O}$ and $\ce{H}$ I have, if I have $\pu{6 g}$ of $\ce{O2}$?

What if I know I have $\pu{6 g}$ of $\ce{H2O}$, how would I find grams of $\ce{H}$ and $\ce{O2}$?

What if I know I have $\pu{6 g}$ of $\ce{H}$, how would I find out how many grams of $\ce{H2O}$ and $\ce{O2}$?

I found the molar mass of $\ce{H2O}$ to be 18, $\ce{H}$ to be 1, and $\ce{O2}$ to be 32.

Comment: I'd double check the problem. Hydrogen won't exist as the atom but rather as the diatomic molecule. It could be that that an "artificial" problem was made-up using just an atom of hydrogen, but that would be weird.

Comment: Double-check the reaction and don't omit molar mass units.

Comment: @MaxW yea, it is an artificial problem, I just want to know if there is a way to solve it.

Comment: @andselisk Is there a way to solve it, and what do you mean molar mass units, isn't that amu or g/mol?

Comment: Using your second balanced equation gives the reaction as four hydrogen atoms plus one oxygen molecule yields two water molecules. The ratios of atom counts hold. A mole is just a big counting number like a million or a billion. Thus you have to figure out how many moles of oxygen molecules there are in 6 grams of oxygen molecules and work out the rest of the ratios in moles. You'd then convert to grams as needed.

Comment: @Rixwaan I don't know what units there are as you haven't typed any. You can solve for any reaction, the question is how meaningful the result will be. Stray hydrogen looks very suspicious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We know that $$\ce{H2O molar mass is approximately 18 g/mol}$$
$$\ce{H molar mass is approximately 1g/mol}$$
$$\ce{O molar mass is approximately 16g/mol}$$

So $\ce{2H is 2/18 = 1/9 of the H2O mass}$ and 
$\ce{O is 16/18 = 8/9 of the H2O mass}$ 
Since you have **6g** of $\ce{H2O}$ that means you'll have
$$\ce{6/18 = 1/3 mol of H2O}$$
Then 
$$\ce{H mass would be approximately 1/3 * 1/9 g}$$
$$\ce{O mass would be approximately 1/3 * 8/9 g}$$

N.b: results will be very approximate